# What are real use cases of having a Protected constructor in java?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, protected

I already know that a class with a private constructor is generally used to implement a Singleton pattern.
I also know that a class with a protected constructor can be instantiated by a subclass or a class in the same package.

So what could be examples of usage of a protected constructor?
Only the ones where we need a Singleton on package level? (i.e. single instance guaranteed only across packages?)

Is there any other design pattern, or use case,  that uses a protected constructor?

Comment: Basically, every time a class is not indended to be instantiated directly, and only subclasses can be. For example, an abstract class. The template  pattern for example generally uses a protected constructor.

Comment: Example classes with protected constructors: `java.lang.Throwable`, `java.io.Reader`, `java.time.Clock`, `java.util.AbstractCollection`. All of these are obviously designed for inheritance.